# SimpleXML expecting array error PHP

Tags: php, arrays, xml, sorting, simplexml

ok below is my code

```
<?php
// Last 10 Jobs
function last10IT(){
$xml = simplexml_load_file('http://www.cv-library.co.uk/cgi-bin/feed.xml?affid=101899');


$new_array = array();
//$limit = 5;
//$c = 0;
foreach ($xml->jobs->job as $job) {
//    if ($limit == $c) {
//        break;
//    }
    $jobref = $job->jobref;
    $title = $job->title;
    $date = $job->date;
    $new_array[$jobref.$date] = array(
        'jobref' => $jobref,
        'date' => $date,
        'title' => $title,
        'salary' => $job->salary,
        'location' => $job->location,
    );
}
}
ksort($new_array);
$showl = 10;
$n = 0;
foreach ($new_array as $date => $listing) {

    print $listing['title'] . PHP_EOL;

}
?>
```

All I want it to do is filter by category & display a max of 10 results
for example
IT
so is there a way I can pass the category value into the function that I want it to filter by 
instead of having to replicate for each category

All I get is :

> Warning: ksort() expects parameter 1 to be array, null given in
>   C:\wamp\www\RECRUITMENTFAIR\functions.php on line 28

Please help guys

It something SO simple causing this error but its driving me mad because I just cannot see it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

it is relative simple: you try to use the variable `$new_array` out of scope: 
it is defined within your `last10IT()` function, but the function ends after the first `foreach`.

you should either return the array and call the function to get the array or move the part with the ksort and the printing into the function, depending on your needs.

Comment: ok so I just moved it inside the closing } tag
now all i get is 
Warrning: simplexml_load_file(http://www.cv-library.co.uk/cgi-bin/feed.xml?affid=101899&amp;limit=10): failed to open stream: Unknown Error in C:\wamp\www\RECRUITMENTFAIR\functions.php on line 4

Answer (score 0):

Also was having issues by not having the PHP Extension xmlrpc enabled !
what a tool !
Thats why i was getting failed to open half the time